# Same code not working with new parameters

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

I am trying to get this code to paste the House # if the associated water and light bills are one month late or more. I have this exact same code running perfectly fine with another set of similar data in the same workbook (though different sheets), but I get "Run.time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error" on the indicated line when I run it. Why does this code not work in these circumstances?

```
'General Variables
    Dim myDate As Integer
    Dim getDate As String
    Dim colPaste As String
    Dim colPensionNumb As String
    Dim colPaste3 As String
    Dim colPaste2 As String
    Dim colCelular As String
    Dim colPaste4 As String
    Dim colPaste5 As String

    'Agua Variables
    Dim aguaNumb As Integer
    Dim aguaNumb2 As Integer
    Dim colNameAgua As String
    Dim colPasteA As String

    'Luz Variables
    Dim luzNumb As Integer
    Dim luzNumb2 As Integer
    Dim colNameLuz As String
    Dim colPasteL As String

    'General Values
    colPaste = "A"
    colCelular = "G"
    colPensionNumb = "H"
    myDate = Month(Date)
    colPaste3 = "E"
    colPaste4 = "F"
    colPaste5 = "G"

    'Agua Values
    colNameAgua = "C"
    colPasteA = "B"

    'Luz Values
    colNameLuz = "D"
    colPasteL = "C"


    'Agua
     For aguaNumb = 3 To 5
        If Month(Worksheets("Proxima Lectura").Range(colNameAgua & aguaNumb).Value) < myDate - 1 Then
            ' ---------THE FOLLOWING LINE IS WHERE THE ERROR OCCURS------------
            Worksheets("Title Page").Range(colPasteA & aguaNumb).Value = Worksheets("Proxima Lectura").Range(colNameAgua & aguaNumb).Value
        End If
     Next aguaNumb
```

**EDIT**

Now the code doesn't give me an error, but it's not giving me any results from the line within the IF statement

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: I'm using Excel 2013

Comment: I get no error with that segment of code. It must be something else, either in your worksheet, or in another book, etc. Without more details / screenshot, etc, it is hard/impossible to say.

Comment: Stackoverflow won't let me post images unless I have 10 rep points... However, I've added some message boxes and it seems that the line that I need to work just gets skipped. It gives me absolutely no results (a.k.a. It doesn't change any of the info it should)

Comment: Can you go into the cells C3,C4,C5 in "Proxima Lectura" sheet. Go into the cell (by double clicking) and copy everything that appears in the text box above the column labels? I expect it is a date of some sort, but need to see exactly what you have in those cells.

Comment: ...And paste contents here, in the comments, I meant to add.

Comment: (C3) 26-08-2014
(C4) *blank*     
(C5) 19-08-2014

Comment: As I thought - your cell values test cases do not satisfy the `IF` condition. See my answer below. Consider marking one of them as an answer, if they helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your comments you say that cells "C3" = 26-08-2014 "C4" blank "C5" 19-08-2014. So...when you run your macro, of course it will skip the `IF` code, because the month is August which does not satisfy the `IF` condition.

Try your code extract but with dates in "C3" = 26-06-2014, "C4" = 26-05-2014, "C5" = 26-03-2014. I think you will find it works.

Comment: Wow....I feel like whenever someone points out my errors they're always so obvious... I guess that's the point of learning and studying, right?

Answer (score 0):

The error is in this specific segment:

```
Month(Worksheets("Proxima Lectura").Range(colNameAgua & aguaNumb).Value) < myDate - 1
```

All you need to do is to change the declaration of `myDate` to

```
Dim myDate as Integer
```

The problem is you are subtracting from a string (`myDate` is dimensioned as a string in the beginning).

Comment: Although bad practice, Excel VBA 2010 does actually coerce myDate to integer for this calculation... No error here.

Comment: The error occurs on the line within the IF statement. Well, really, it seems to just get skipped. Running it results in no changes.

Comment: I think i reconize the error.Is your cell `range(colNameAgua & aguaNumb)` contains date value?

Comment: It does, but that's why I called on the `MONTH()` function. Is there another way to do it?

Comment: why you remove 1 from mydate?

Comment: I need to see which bills are over one month old, so I figured subtracting 1 from the current month and telling excel to select everything less than that would give me everything more than 1 month old.